# ReactJS call class method in Button after map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 JS classes: App.jsx, Note.jsx.

Note.jsx:

```
export default class Note{
  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  changeNoteStatus(){
   console.log(this.text);
  }
}
```

In App.jsx:

```
let tmpNote = new Note(String(this.state.value));
     this.notes.push({key:this.currId, value:tmpNote});
```

and in App.jsx i can call the changeNoteStatus() on a simple object but after creating a list of Note and using map() function:

```
return this.notes.map((obj) =>
       <div className="note" onClick={obj.value.changeNoteStatus} key={obj.key} id={"note_" + obj.key}/>
)
```

The method doesn't recognize class field anymore (like this.text).

I have tried `{this.notes[obj.key].changeNoteStatu}` in mapping function too.

Please help me.

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem. Stack Snippets support ReactJS, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use it in an `onClick` like that, the handler will get called with the wrong `this` value.

One solution is to use `Function#bind`:

```
onClick={obj.value.changeNoteStatus.bind(obj.value)}
// --------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...but depending on how your overall code is structured, there may be more concise or efficient ways of doing it.